# Swapping the contents od div (with more than 3 div)

Tags: jquery

I have an RSS reader application in j query, with 8 div section and 8 categories.On selecting a particular category inside a div,the div with that category should automatically get replaced by the contents in the first div.

I need a demo for swapping the contents on div (with more than 3 div).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/ it has a number of demos to suit your needs.

Comment: Hi, where can i get the swap.jquery.js plug in ?